# passing generic python class by reference with type initialized (AttributeError: 'typing.TypeVar' object has no attribute)

Tags: python, generics

This is the pseudo code for what I wish to achieve.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def run():
        print("lul")

class Test[T]():
    def run(self):
        return T.run()

t = Test[A]()
t = t.run()
```

error:

```
File ".../main.py", line 13, in test
    return T.run()
           ^^^^^
AttributeError: 'typing.TypeVar' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Is this possible? Or an explanation as to why it isn't or an alternative would be appreciated.

As a side note, in my specific actual scenario it is not possible to pass `A` by reference to `T` in any way.

Comment: A `@classmethod` needs to have a first parameter `cls`. Use `@staticmethod` if you don't need to refer to the class.

Comment: Python doesn't have generic classes like this. Generic types are just used for type hinting, not for creating actual classes.